# Is there a faster way to vectorize a matrix than this?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, code-review

I want to put all the columns stacked up, as a vector.

The fastest code I could come up with was

```
Transpose[{Flatten[Transpose[A]]}]
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: This is about 30% to 40% faster for matrices of shape 1000x1000: `ArrayReshape[Transpose[A], {Times @@ Dimensions[A], 1}]`

Comment: And seems to be up to 50% faster in other instances!

Comment: Is keeping the extra dimension beneficial?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that here you are wasting a lot of time by transposing twice (this is the slowest operation here). See the breakdown of timings of your code here:

```
    A = ArrayReshape[Range[1000^2], {1000, 1000}];

    RepeatedTiming[transposeA = Transpose[A];]

(* {0.0034, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[flattenA = Flatten[transposeA];]

(* {0.00275, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[Transpose[{flattenA}];]

(* {0.00555, Null}

If instead we use (as I suggested in the comment above) `ArrayReshape[Transpose[A], {Times @@ Dimensions[A], 1}]` then the timings are a lot more favourable: *)

RepeatedTiming[transposeA = Transpose[A];]
```

> {0.0034, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[dimA = Times @@ Dimensions[A];]
```

> {2.04*10^-6, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[ArrayReshape[transposeA, {dimA,1}];]
```

> {0.00263, Null}

These result in the following differences:

```
RepeatedTiming[Transpose[{Flatten[Transpose[A]]}];]
```

> {0.0122, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[ArrayReshape[Transpose[A], {Times @@ Dimensions[A], 1}];]
```

> {0.0032, Null}

In this case, the new code is nearly 4 times faster.

Comment: Many thanksDaniel ;)